# Uso de tiempo futuro como imperativo

Tags: gramática

En una serie de Netflix "La Víctima Número Ocho" (España) vi lo siguiente:

"***Verás**, Adila, hay un tema del que te queríamos hablar.*"

¿Por qué "*verás*" se usó en tiempo futuro? ¿Por qué no se usó "ve"?

P.s. Por adelantado agradezco que corrijan errores en mi pregunta en caso de que los haya.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No tiene valor de imperativo, no se le está mandando que vea. De hecho, *ver* no se usa casi nunca en imperativo. En imperativo se suele usar *mirar*, porque la gente no controla lo que ve, sino lo que mira. Así, podría decirse:

> "Mira, Adila, hay un tema del que te queríamos hablar."

En el caso de *ver*, como he dicho, no se le está mandando que vea, sino que se le está indicando que, si escucha la explicación, verá ([*2. tr. Percibir con la inteligencia algo, comprenderlo*](https://dle.rae.es/ver?m=form)).

Puede verse que *mira* en este sentido equivale al inglés *look*, mientras que *verás* funciona como *you'll see*.

Comment: Entiendo. Interesante. De lo que sé, también se usa "fijarse" en casi mismo sentido como "mirar"...

Comment: Pero eso conduce a una cuestión interesante, la de las situaciones en las que el tiempo futuro en efecto tiene valor de imperativo, por lo menos en lo que a lo semántico se refiere. Por ejemplo, si alguien me dice "Irás al mercado y me comprarás algo", está bien claro que dicha persona manda que lo haga, aunque no haya dicho nada en imperativo.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Y también están las situaciones en las que el presente de indicativo tiene valor de imperativo: "Vas al mercado y me compras algo". O el condicional, si nos ponemos en plan manipulador: "Si de verdad me quisieras, irías al mercado y me comprarías algo".